# How to add a return statement for a method - beginner

Tags: java

When i enter a value (`202 cents`) it should give me this amount either in `5 cents or 2 cents` coins. Everything works fine in my code, but the output is given as System.out statement in the `TwoCent` and `FiveCent` class it self. WHat i want to do is to `return` the number of `5 cents` and `2 cents` coins so that i could capture and display it in my `Test` class.

Note: In the code below, the number of 2 and 5 cents coins are returned(displayed/printed to the console) from that class it self. but i want to modify the code so those methods (in the `TwoCents` and `FiveCents` classes) will `return` and `int` may be with the amount of coins. I should be able to get these values and display from the `Test` class only.

```
   public abstract class Coin {
    protected Coin co;
    public abstract void finCoin(Money m);
    public void setnext(Coin c) {
        co = c;
    }
}

public class TwoCent extends Coin{

    @Override
    public void finCoin(Money m) {
        if(m.getChange()%2==0){
          System.out.PrintLn("Return "+ m.getChange/2);
    else {
        int remainngCoins=m.getChange()*((m.getChange/2)*2));
        m.setChange(remainngCoins);
        co.setnext(m);
    }
}


public class FiveCent extends Coin{

    @Override
    public void finCoin(Money m) {
        if(m.getChange()%5==0){
          System.out.PrintLn("Return "+ m.getChange/5);
    else {
        int remainngCoins=m.getChange()*((m.getChange/5)*5));
        m.setChange(remainngCoins);
        co.setnext(m);
    }
}

public class Test {
public void showcoin(){
Coin f = new FiveCent();
        Cash t = new TwoCent();

        f.setSuccessor(t);

        Money cr = new Money(200);
        f.finCoin(cr);
}
}
```

Comment: How does that even compile? You're implementing `public abstract int finCoin` as `public void finCoin` instead of `public int finCoin`.

Comment: Edited. I made some last min changes before posting the code.

Comment: @user1315906 You should return your value at the end of method (return xxx) and collect it in calling method.

Comment: @smit Ok. Say if i return the value `int`. How am i going to  retrieve it from the `Test` Class. Also please look at the `        m.setChange(remainngCoins);
` line. The number of coins remaining will be sent to the 2nd class. So the number of coins should be returned from that class as well.

Comment: @user1315906 I don't know what your setChange() method doing exactly as I cant see its implementation in your code, However you should take a look at answers given by Abu and Christoph Gerstner.

Comment: @smit setChange is just setting the number of coins that was remaining. I have added a detail comment to Christoph Gerstner Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, the definition of the abstract class Coin already describes that the method finCoin(Money m) must return an int. But in neither of the implementations (FiveCent and TwoCent) this value gets returned.

What you do is replace the System.out.println stuff with a return like this:

**instead of**

```
 @Override
public void finCoin(Money m) {
    if(m.getChange()%5==0){
      System.out.PrintLn("Return "+ m.getChange/5);
else {
    int remainngCoins=m.getChange()*((m.getChange/5)*5));
    m.setChange(remainngCoins);
    co.setnext(m);
}
```

** you do **

```
 @Override
public int finCoin(Money m) {   // VERY IMPORTANT replace void by int
    if(m.getChange()%5==0){
      // System.out.PrintLn("Return "+ m.getChange/5);
      return m.getChange/5;   // thats how you return a value and end this method call
    else {
      int remainngCoins=m.getChange()*((m.getChange/5)*5));
      m.setChange(remainngCoins);
      co.setnext(m);
    }
    return 0;   // this is just a guess but you MUST return something
}
```

Comment: Well. Say if the user enters `22` as the value of coins. I will try doing a `modulus` like 22%5 and see if its equal to 0. If so i will return it. If it's not equal to 0. I will divide `22/5` and the remaining and return it and also in the same time pass it on to the `TwoCents` class so it can do it's calculations and return. Basically, i need to get both the return values (from the 2 classes) be accessible from `Test` class

Comment: @user1315906 and Christopher If you do this 22/5, then it will be a double number and if you return that number withour proper cast it will throe error.

Comment: Yes i will be casting it. Let's just say it's going to return `4`. Four 5 cent coins. and the remaining 2 cents will be passed to the TwoCents class to see how many 2cent coins it could return

Comment: @user1315906 So where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is, i don't want to have a `sysout` statement in those classes, but return the number of 5 cents and 2 cents coins to the Test class where the function (`f.finCoin(cr);`) is being called. So i could `sysout`the number of coins from there.

Comment: Basically, i want to edit the code in someway so that it returns both the 2 cents and 5 cents coins from just 1 function call. I am thinking of adding an array, and saving the values to it, and access the number of coins from that. But this might not be the best approach.

Comment: @user1315906 You can also return values from those classes. and collect those returned values in TEST class from where you are calling that method. How you implement it (I mean you logic) its all depends on you.

Comment: @smit the / operator is overloaded and works for int as well, the result of 22/5 will be an int (the compiler casts automatically)

Comment: @smit Yes, exactly. That's my code that i have pasted in my question. but i don't have a clue how to return 2 values from 1 function call.

Comment: @ChristophGerstner Okay as you say it will taken care of by compiler. But It will return 0 instead of remaining coin.

Comment: hm, then I don't get it... if(m.getChange()%5==0) already makes sure that there is no rest and that m.getChange is dividable by 5.. so what happens to the rest?

Comment: I mean it is in the else statement where it collecs the remaining coins, right? Can't you make a call from there to the TwoCoin instance ?

Comment: If the user wants 20 coins. 20%5 is equal to 0. meaning there is no need to give change in 2cents (so i will be returning this value to the user) and if the user enters 22. and 24%5 = 4, which is not a 0. meaning we have to give the user some coins in 2cents. So i will pass the remaining 4 cents to the other class, so it will figure out how many 2 cents coins it can give.

Comment: @user1315906 Did you even tried to debug the code why you are getting wrong values?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code. it's only that i need to know how to return values from 2 method calls.

Comment: @user1315906 YOu accepted the answer. I hope you got your way to correct it. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add return type first in order for your method to return something.

A simple example :

```
public int getInteger(){

int i = 10;
return i;

// see the return type is int and 
// I am returning an integer value 10
}
```

Comment: Yes, but according to the requirement i think i have to do something more than returning the int.

Comment: @user1315906 I was just trying to explain how you return something from a method. And thats not the reason to down vote I suppose